# Find vector of strings in list (R)

Tags: r

I have a list, in which each element is a vector of strings, as:

```
l <- list(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"))
```

I want to find the index of the element in `l` that contains a specific vector of strings, as `c("a", "b")`. How do I do that? I thought `which(l %in% c("a", "b"))` should work, but it returns `integer(0)` instead of `1`.

Comment: Try `which(sapply(l,function(x) all(c("a","b") %in% x)))`.

Comment: Or `which(sapply(l, identical, c("a", "b")))` if order matters.

Comment: Or, using your approach with `%in%`, `which(l %in% list(c("a", "b")))` works.

Comment: Awesome! Needless to say, any of your suggestions works equally well for my problem. However, @Gregor's second suggestion nicely illustrates my error, so I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%in%` checks presence of elements of the LHS among elements of the RHS. To treat `c("a", "b")` as a single element of the RHS, it needs to be in a list:

```
which(l %in% list(c("a", "b")))
```

Other possibilities are to go element-by-element through `l` with `sapply`, such as

```
which(sapply(l,function(x) all(c("a","b") %in% x)))
# order doesn't matter, other elements allowed

which(sapply(l, identical, c("a", "b"))) # exact match, in order
```